# Joining 3 Table with more than 1 relation

Tags: mysql, join

```
mtOrder
-------
idOrder idCust
1       123423      
2       324602

dtOrderBox
----------
idOrder     idBox    idItem   Quantity  usedBox
1           1        39       2         1
1           2        34       30        0
1           3        39       2         1
2           1        39       10        1
2           2        24       5         0

dtOrderDetail
-------------
idOrder    idBox     idItem  Quantity
1          1         45      10
1          3         46      10
2          1         45      15
```

As pictured above, the 3 Table where linked by `idOrder`, and `dtOrderBox` and `dtOrderDetail` also linked again by `idBox`. `dtOrderBox` is used to record box and also item without box. `dtOrderDetail` is used to record the content of the Box that being order in `dtOrderBox`.

The problem lies, when i tried to join this tree table together

```
select * from mtOrder
Join dtOrderBox on dtOrderBox.idOrder = mtOrder.idOrder
Join dtOrderDetail on dtOrderDetail.idOrder = mtOrder.idOrder and dtOrderDetail.idBox = dtOrderBox.idBox
```

Using this, the result will show all item in dtOrderBox that using Box. The Item that doesn't using box (as shown in `dtOrderBox` column `usedBox`) won't show.
Thanks for the help!

```
Desired Result
--------------
idOrder   idBox   idItem Quantity
1         1       45     20
1         2       34     30 
1         3       46     20
2         1       45     150
2         2       24     5
```

Comment: If you will use Left Join then "dtOrderDetail.idOrder = mtOrder.idOrder" this condition is not required.

Comment: @RaviHirani if i don't use "dtOrderDetail.idOrder = mtOrder.idOrder" then the result of `dtOrderDetail` and `dtOrderBox` won't match..

Comment: It would also have greatly helped if you had showed us the desired output.  Keep this in mind when you ask future questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:-

```
SELECT mtOrder.*,dtOrderBox.*,dtOrderDetail.* 
FROM mtOrder
LEFT JOIN dtOrderBox ON mtOrder.idOrder = dtOrderBox.idOrder
LEFT JOIN dtOrderDetail ON dtOrderDetail.idBox = dtOrderBox.idBox
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use left join :

```
select mtOrder.idOrder, mtOrder.idCust, 
      dtOrderBox.idItem, dtOrderBox.Quantity, dtOrderBox.usedBox, 
      dtOrderDetail.Quantity 
from mtOrder
Left Join dtOrderBox on dtOrderBox.idOrder = mtOrder.idOrder
Left Join dtOrderDetail on dtOrderDetail.idOrder = mtOrder.idOrder and dtOrderDetail.idBox = dtOrderBox.idBox
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left joins to retain records from the `dtOrderBox` table which do not match to anything.

```
SELECT m.*, dob.*, dod.*
FROM mtOrder m
LEFT JOIN dtOrderBox dob
    ON dob.idOrder = m.idOrder
LEFT JOIN dtOrderDetail dod
    ON dod.idOrder = m.idOrder AND dod.idBox = dob.idBox
```

Comment: I've tried this method before..
It doesn't retain the records

Comment: I believe every answer given is resorting to using a `LEFT JOIN`.  Why won't this work for your case?

Comment: The item which doesn't have counterpart in `dtOrderDetail` doesn't want to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT mo.*,dob.*,dod.* 
FROM mtOrder as mo
LEFT JOIN dtOrderBox as dob ON mo.idOrder = dob.idOrder
LEFT JOIN dtOrderDetail as dod ON dod.idBox = dob.idBox and dod.idBox = dob.idBox
```